# How to build the largest sambusa

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

I was making sambusa last night.  Typically when mama cooks them she has small circles of dough, but mama is not here so I went to the store and bought the dough, and it came in the shape of a rectangle. Now I like the filling more than I like the fried dough. So my problem is how can I fold this rectangular sheet to give me a sambusa with the largest volume for the yummy filling?   I am disallowing cutting the dough for two reason, it makes the problem trivial (could just rearrange the dough atoms into a perfect sphere) and mama never cut her dough when she made them.

Here is a picture of what I tried to make:

[image: Sambusa]

Comment: They look delicious. The question looks a little vague. If you are really making sambusa, having a huge sambusa may prove to be a practically bad idea as what is inside will not be fried properly (The one in the picture looks just right). Mathematically, are you considering tetrahedrons, and the question is given an $a\times b$ rectangle what is the volume of the largest tetrahedron I can construct out of it by cutting it (or folding it)?

Comment: @LordSoth Yes, they are tasty.  Ok, I will try to be more clear. Also, I have never sheet anyone cut dough for this, typical is to have small circles, but the store bought dough was in long rectangle shape.

Comment: @LordSoth could you point me in direction of some entry level information which I can read more about this problem?  Please note, that I know 2nd year calcululs not real analysis.